# The ConnectionString property has not been initialized

Tags: asp.net

My connection string is placed in web.config as follows.

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="empcon" connectionString="Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Password=abc;Initial Catalog=db5pmto8pm;Data Source=SOWMYA-3BBF60D0\SOWMYA" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and the code of program is...

```
public partial class empoperations : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    string constr = null;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["empcon"].ToString();
         if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            fillemps();
        }
    }
    public void fillemps()
    {
        dlstemps.Items.Clear();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["empcon"].ConnectionString);
        con.ConnectionString = constr;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from emp";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        SqlDataReader reader;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ListItem lt = new ListItem();
                lt.Text = reader["ename"].ToString();
                lt.Value = reader["empno"].ToString();
                dlstemps.Items.Add(lt);
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            lblerror.Text = er.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
```

i am totally new to programing....

i am able to run this application with er.message in label control as "the connection string property has not been initialized"

i need to retrieve the list of names of employees from the emp table in database into the dropdownlist and show them to the user...

can any one please fix it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assigning `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["empcon"].ToString();` to `string constr`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["empcon"].ToString();
    ...
```

will probably solve your problem for the time being.

Comment: Or he can remove the con.Connection = constr; line, which is what is removing the connection string from the Connection object.

Comment: @sowmya Great - then you should tick the most helpful answer to accept it: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Where are you initializing your `constr` variable?  It looks like you can leave that line out.

Also: just use `using`

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["empcon"].ConnectionString)
{
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
       cmd.Connection = con;
       //Rest of your code here
    }
}
```

Side note:  Don't use `Select * From`.  Call out your columns: `Select empname, empno From...`

Comment: You can also use `using(SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())` to create a `SqlCommand` (or the correctly-typed variant for your connection) with the connection prepopulated. You then have to set the SQL text separately whereas if you `new SqlCommand()` you can pass the SQL into the constructor too.